# Parsing a HTML alike code in Objective-C

Tags: html, objective-c, regex, hpple

I'm new to Objective-C programming and while I'm trying to parse SAMI code
I found some difficulties with using Hpple to properly parse some section from the file.

SAMI body code syntex follows

```
<Sync Start=100><P Class=ENCC>This is Subtitle
<Sync Start=200><P Class=ENCC><b>This is Bold Subtitle</b>
<Sync Start=300><P Class=ENCC><font color=ff0000>This is Red Subtitle
<Sync Start=400><P Class=ENCC>&nbsp; 
<Sync Start=500><P Class=ENCC><font color=ffffff>Back to White Subtitle
```

and so for on.

There was no problem with parsing sync time(number) and Subtitle language(ENCC) using Hpple, but I can't get the content of subtitlte including inner tags.

Is there is a way to parse useing Hpple with this? Or do I have to use regular expression to solve this? If I have to use regular expression then how can I set up the match?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1256925